# Rendering and Rerendering a command button after submitting a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, commandbutton, save-and-new

I have a two command buttons that are able to save a record. One button fully submits the record and sends it to the edit view. The other save button will update the record if there is anything the user would like to change. I want to make it so the update button only appears in the edit view page, and the submit button shows in the initial creation of the new record to be submitted.

**Page**

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="buttonSection">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputPanel id="buttonPanel">
                <div align="right">
                    <apex:commandButton value="UPDATE" action="{!pageUpdate}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save & Submit Request" action="{!SaveAndSubmit}" reRender="msgs, buttonPanel" status="AjaxStatus" id="btnSubmit" rendered="{!not(inSubmissionProcess)}"/>
                    <apex:actionStatus id="AjaxStatus" onstart="DisableButton()" onstop="EnableButton()"></apex:actionStatus>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate" action="{!Cancel}"/>  
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**Controller**

```
public Boolean getInSubmissionProcess() {

        if(inSubmissionProcess == null) {

            if(cardRequest.ID == null) {

                inSubmissionProcess = false;

            }

            else {

                inSubmissionProcess = true;

            }

        }

        return inSubmissionProcess;

    }
```

What must I do differently to have the update button show on the edit page, and the submit button show on the record creation page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lazy load of the boolean is causing it to not update if `cardRequest.ID` changes. One it is set to false it will never update to true cause it is no longer null

Maybe the solution is simply changing to:

```
public Boolean getInSubmissionProcess() {

            if(cardRequest.ID == null) {
                inSubmissionProcess = true;
            }
            else {
                inSubmissionProcess = false;
            }
        return inSubmissionProcess;
    }
```

Modified return value based on your comments below

Here is a full example for you to give a try:

**Class**

```
public class myExample{

    public boolean iHaveRan = false;
    public boolean shouldIRender;

    public boolean getshouldIRender(){

        if(iHaveRan == false)
            shouldIRender = true;
        else
            shouldIRender = false;

        return shouldIRender;


    }

    public void IHaveBeenClicked(){
        iHaveRan = true;
    }


}
```

You technically do not even need the additional properties and is can be shortened to

```
public class myExample{

    public boolean iHaveRan = false;

    public boolean getshouldIRender(){

        return !iHaveRan; //In your case it would be cardRequest.Id != null


    }

    public void IHaveBeenClicked(){
        iHaveRan = true;
    }


}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myExample">


    <apex:form id="theForm">

        <apex:commandButton action="{!iHaveBeenClicked}" rerender="theForm" rendered="{!shouldIRender}" value="ClickMe"/>

        <apex:outPutText value="I Have Been Clicked" rendered="{!!shouldIRender}"/>

    </apex:form>



</apex:page>
```

Comment: According to your code you are basing the true or false off of the fact that `cardRequest.ID` is null or not. I cannot say what your logic should be as I do not know what you are trying to do other than that. if the `cardRequest.ID` is null `InSubmissionProcess` will be false otherwise it will be true. Maybe you should switch them if you want it to be true when `cardRequest.ID` is null

Comment: @Mr.HelpMe - Well if you have `rendered={!inSubmissionProcess}` and it is not rendering then the value if FALSE. If you want it to be TRUE then change the way you set the value of the variable. seems to me you want it to be TRUE when the Id is Null which means your getter is set up to return the incorrect values so flip the true and false returns around. This is in addition to the lazy loading issue

Comment: Remember when we talked about asking a good question? Since the question relates to what the definition of `inSubmissionProcess` is a paragraph about how you want to determine if it should be true or not would have been helpful and prevented this discussion. As it stands all we have to go by is what is in your code when it relates to what you wanted returned

Comment: Ok, I am going to work up and example to show you it is working, then you can adapt as needed. Maybe that will help. give me a few minutes

Comment: @Mr.HelpMe - full working example for you to see that it is working as expected. And don't post code in comments as it is completely unreadable

Comment: @Mr.HelpMe - confirm that you installed the class and page exactly as I have it and visited the mytestPage to see that it works. As far as the error, do you have an extension set? is there a getter in that extension names shouldIrun?

Comment: Unknown property 'Business_Card_Request__cStandardController.shouldProcessRun' : I even "adapted as needed" and now I have this error. Why do I have this even though my controller clearly recognizes this and compiles without error?